# Adding a new function to count comments in a Class based view

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying to get the count of comments in my comment section

I have added this function to the models to get the count, I am getting `'ItemDetailView' object has no attribute 'comment'` error

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        ('New', 'New'),
        ('True', 'True'),
        ('False', 'False'),
    )
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="ItemComments")
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS, default='New')

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} by {}'.format(self.subject, str(self.user.username))

    def total_comments(self):
        return self.comment.count()
```

I have also included it in the views which i think might be the reason for not working properly

```
class ItemDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Item
    template_name = "product.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["comments"] = Comment.objects.filter(item=self.object, status='New')
        total_comments = self.comment.total_comments()
        context["total_comments"] = total_comments
        return context
```

Here is the template

```
<h5><span>{{ total_comments }}</span> review for <span>{{object.title|capfirst }}</span></h5>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It mean, your view doesn't have `comment` attribute. You should modify the `context_object_name`:

```
class ItemDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Item
    template_name = "product.html"
    context_object_name = "comment"
```

> Or you can also use the `self.object.total_comments()`

But, prevously you can't use `.count()` for `models.CharField` field, it should be;

```
def total_comments(self):
    if self.comment:
        return len(self.comment)
    return 0
```

> Perhaps you meen want to `.count` total comments for current filter. If yes, you can modify also your context_data.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(item=self.object, status='New')
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context["comments"] = comments
    context["total_comments"] = comments.count()
    return context
```